# Stuck into a Notice: Undefined variable: c

Tags: php, notice

I have this index.php file

```
# Loading configurations.
loadConfiguration('database');
loadConfiguration('site');

# Initializing the database connection.
$db = new database($c['db']['host'], $c['db']['username'], $c['db']['password'], $c['db']['name']);
unset($c['db']['password']);
```

And loadConfiguration() is set as follow:

```
function loadConfiguration($string) { require(path.'config/'.$string.'.con.php'); }
```

I checked that database.con.php and site.con.php are into the config/ folder.
And the only error i get is a **Notice: Undefined variable: c** in the following line

```
$db = new database($c['db']['host'], $c['db']['username'], $c['db']['password'], $c['db']['name']);
```

Here's the database.con.php

```
# Ignore.
if (!defined('APP_ON')) { die('Feel the rain...'); }

$c['db']['host'] = 'localhost';
$c['db']['username'] = 'root';
$c['db']['password'] = '';
$c['db']['name'] = 'name';
```

Here's the site.con.php

```
# Ignore.
if (!defined('APP_ON')) { die('Feel the rain...'); }

/* Site informations */
$c['site']['name'] = 'Namek';
$c['site']['mail'] = 'mail@whocares.com';
$c['site']['enable-email'] = false;
$c['site']['debug-mode'] = true;
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `require`d code is executed within the function, so `$c` is a local variable and not accessible in global scope.

You may either use some fancy design pattern to make `$c` global (e.g. use a Registry (`R::$c`, `R::get('c')`, an Environment (`$this->env->c`), ...) or you could change your configuration loader function to return the name of the file and `require` outside of it:

```
require_once configFile('database');

function configFile($name) {
    return path . 'config/' . $name . '.con.php';
}
```

Comment: Would you suggest the latest over the others? What about using 'global' inside the required file?

Comment: @Charlie: Using `global` won't help. `global` is used to make global variables available locally, not the other way round. I would suggest you to use the last variant. Maybe the other two are better in the long term, i.e. for bigger projects with loads of things to make global, but for smaller projects you probably won't need a Registry ;)

Comment: But what if i declare $c before calling loadConfiguration() and inside the .con.php file i write "global $c;". It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use global variable according security purpose. you can set your variable in registry variable and then access it.